# How to pass message metadata with StreamingTextResponse to useChat?

Tags: next.js, vercel, openai-api, langchain, vercel-ai

I'm trying to pass message metadata with `StreamingTextResponse` and to read it on the client side with `useChat`.

This is the sample code I'm using:

```js
import {NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";
import {experimental_StreamData, Message as VercelChatMessage, StreamingTextResponse} from "ai";
import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import {PromptTemplate} from "langchain/prompts";
import {BytesOutputParser} from "langchain/schema/output_parser";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const messages: VercelChatMessage[] = body.messages ?? [];
    const currentMessageContent = messages[messages.length - 1].content;

    const model = new ChatOpenAI({
      temperature: 0,
      streaming: true,
    });
    const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(`
      You are a cheerful bot that should respond to all questions in an upbeat manner.
      
      User input: {input}
      
      AI response:
    `);
    const outputParser = new BytesOutputParser();
    const chain = prompt
      .pipe(model)
      .pipe(outputParser);
    const stream = await chain.stream({input: currentMessageContent});

    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
  }
  catch (e: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: e.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I tried using `experimental_StreamData()` and passing the data object as the third argument to `StreamingTextResponse()`:

```js
const data = new experimental_StreamData();
data.append({text: new Date().toISOString()});
data.close();

return new StreamingTextResponse(stream, {}, data);
```

However, this just stringifies the data and prepends it to the response message.

What should I change here to pass the data object separately from the response?

Thanks!